# Embedded python3, no "site" module

Tags: c, linux, python-3.x

I'm trying to write some C that implements some Python (on linux), but I'm seeing the following error when running `Py_Initialize()`:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

I have set PYTHONHOME before the initialization, to the lib directory that contains the site package, as demonstrated:

```
Py_SetPythonHome("/foo/lib/python3");

$ ls /foo/lib/python3/site/
__init__.py  __pycache__
```

I've seen similar issues in my googling but this tends to be resolved by setting PYTHONHOME appropriately, which above shows hasn't worked for me.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the python binary (.exe or whatever) path to `PATH`.
2. Add your programs (including python code and libraries) directory to `PYTHONPATH`.